# Where to ask a question about DDR2 internals?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I feel that Intel documentation contains a mistake. I want to ask question and I need a person who understands how DDR2 chips are addressed and familiar with Jedec ESD79-2. This question is about hardware, so I probably should not ask it on Stack Overflow. 99% of users do not care about RAM internals, so SuperUser is probably the wrong place too. Should it be ServerFault? But it is not about server configuration, it is a more theoretical question. Do we have some kind of "hardware" forum?

Comment: Can you expand a little on what aspect of RAM internals you are having an issue with?

Comment: [electronics.se]?  They have a DDR2 tag that appears to hold similar questions.

Comment: @TravisJ Intel G33 chipset PDF says page size of 32M X 16 512Mb chips it supports is 8K, while it should be 16K according to basic algebra and JEDEC standard. Either I do not understand something about dram addressing or Intel manual contains error.

Comment: I don't really understand why this would be inappropriate on Super User. Sure, plenty of people on the site won't care about that. But plenty of people on Stack Overflow don't care about Visual Basic.

Comment: "Super User is a question and answer site for computer enthusiasts and power users" - i'd argue that DDR spec is beyond interest of typical "enthusiast and power user".

Comment: Certainly not. It may be beyond the scope of *most* enthusiasts and power users, but a person who is interested in this type of stuff (e.g., myself) undoubtedly fits the definition of a computer enthusiast and/or power user.

Comment: Note that no Stack Exchange site is a forum... you'll want EE.SE.

Comment: @CodyGray the same way some enthusiasts and power users are interested in programming, but programming questions belong to SO, not SU.

Comment: Note, the **INTEL** document is probably about a host, whereas JEDEC is about the chips.  Chips can be configured in various ways so addressing between two document might seem inconsistent.  IE, host A10 might not connect to DDR A10.

Answer (score 49):

[Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) covers questions from electrical engineering enthusiasts, professionals, and students. That site would be the best fit for your question.

Comment: What does ESD have to do with anything?

Comment: @AndrewMedico ESD is short for Electro Static Discharge, which is what JEDEC ESD79-2 is about. As OP mentions above, his question requires someone with knowledge of JEDEC ESD79-2.

Comment: Despite the name, [JEDEC ESD79-2](https://www.jedec.org/standards-documents/docs/jesd-79-2e) has nothing to do with ESD. It's the standards document which specifies DDR2 SDRAM.

Comment: Lets make up a 3 letter abbreviation for everything in the world! That will not cause confusion at all.

Comment: @duskwuff Hm, that's indeed confusing, considering JEDEC themselves [define ESD](http://www.jedec.org/category/technology-focus-area/esd-electrostatic-discharge-0) as electrostatic discharge and have other standards with the [same naming scheme](http://www.jedec.org/standards-documents/results/jesd625b) for electrostatic discharge. Still, that's the most appropriate site to ask.

Comment: @TylerH all JEDEC Standards have the JESD prefix. There's also JEP for JEDEC Publications and JM for JEDEC Manuals. So JESD presumably = "JEDEC Standards Document".

Comment: I think SO would be appropriate if the internals have to deal with a programming topic, such as setting the DDR registers.  In fact many of the DDR internals are directly related to the setting of these registers and need to interoperate with the host DDR controller.  Mainly try only one first and see how things go.

Comment: @artlessnoise Sure, but the topic OP is interested in doesn't seem to be about programming, even on a low level. JEDEC ESD79-2 covers  "[...] pinout, addressing, functional description, features, ac and dc parametrics, truth tables, and packages" all sound like hardware things to me, more or less.

Comment: See Chapter 3.4 (Programming the mode and extended mode registers) which is  programming related.  CAS, powerdown, bursting, precharge, clocking and commands are related to the programming task of making the host (CPUs) and DDR talk to each other optimally.  That is over 50% of the standard document.  I doubt his question had to do with pin-out.  How and when to use ODT is partially programming (as it involves the mode registers); it is also doing with the layout of the chips on the board.  Chapters 3 and 4 are germane to SO Q&A which is a majority of the document.